# Linked-list / pointer with this form list[0]

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm working on linked-list in C, and I encounter this problem: I don't understand the following statement.
Here my structure for my linked list

```
typedef struct node {
   int value; 
   struct node *next;
} node;
```

and here is the code I'm working on :

```
void reverse(reverse **list)`void reverse(reverse **list)
{
    struct node * prev = NULL;
    struct node * next;
    struct node * current = list[0];
    while(current!= NULL)
    {
        next = current­>next;
        current­>next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next ;
    } 
    list[0] = prev; ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
}
```

What does the list[0] mean? Is it the first element of my linked-list?
I know my question seems stupid, but I can't find my answer anywhere.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: It's linked-list code from someone who thinks that arrays and pointers are the same and so writes obfuscated gunge:(

Comment: why is your function and your struct type both called `reverse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list[0]` is a pointer to the first node, and `list` is a pointer to that pointer.

`list[0]` is identical to `*(list+0)`, which is identical to `*(list)` or `*list`.

It is just a different form of syntax, it doesn't mean that `list` points to an array.

The address of the pointer to the first node is passed to the function `reverse`. Then that pointer to the pointer is dereferenced (`*list`), so the original pointer outside the function gets modified. If you didn't do that the original pointer wouldn't change and it would no longer point to the start of the list.